# How can you imply some parts of the generic from usage in TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm sure there is a way to do this, but I'm not quite sure how I'd go about doing this. We have a method called `createActions`, which takes an object type and a string to act as the key.

```js
function createActions<T, Tkey extends string>(key: Tkey) {
    return function(obj: T) {
        return {[key]: obj}
    }
}
```

I'd like to be able to infer Tkey – however, `T` should be defined for good typing. The use case is so that I can access whatever property the developer defines in a well-typed way. In other words, if the supplied key is `a`, `createActions('a')({}).b` will throw a compiler error since `b` does not exist on type `{a: {}}`.

This is a bit of an extrapolation of the actual implementation, which can be found here: https://github.com/CaliStyle/ngrx-poly/blob/master/src/app/ngrx-poly/actions/depth-one-action-map.ts.
 Does anyone know how to do something like this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In TypeScript is it possible to infer string literal types for Discriminated Unions from input type of string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57325035/in-typescript-is-it-possible-to-infer-string-literal-types-for-discriminated-uni)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use type as value (or correctly infer generic class type from constructor parameter)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56043642/can-i-use-type-as-value-or-correctly-infer-generic-class-type-from-constructor)

Comment: [Relevant GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242)

Answer (score 2):

Simply declare the type parameter at the appropriate level, that which corresponds to its parameter inference context, to gain the inference desired

```
function createActions<Tkey extends string>(key: Tkey) {
    return function<T>(obj: T) {
        return {[key]: obj};
    };
}

const createPerson = createActions('person');

const hasPerson = createPerson({name: 'Robert', id: 1});

console.log(hasPerson.person.name);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBATgUwIZTQQWvMAZwB4AVAazQE9E0APbMAE0MUKhRjAHMA+ACkpUAXIgrUAlIgDeAKESJ0UECiShIsBGQFwARgCtRpKXIUKlKpNMQBtIQF1Re-YgC+AbnlvPr2bIgI7MjoWGgACmgohAiIALzBmNh4mkT8AEQADpHRYGkSnv6BUIgAFhiEEVEx8aiJ4dkI-NZgGAC2aKJpAEp6kVBpADSIMEyiAIxu+X5lFQ1gAHRZVQst7bJAA)

Comment: I need the <T> generic at the top level because it returns an object map of functions, as in the example I posted.

Comment: So you are saying you need to _fix_ `T` to _prevent_ it from being inferred later?

Comment: Kinda. T and Tkey need to be fixed, and both need to be declared on the top level. This is because it returns an object of functions, and they all use that T and Tkey. It's just that, since Tkey is the exact same as the function argument, there should be someway to have Tkey inferred automatically, so that I can call `createActions<SomeTValue>('myKeyValue')`

Comment: It looks like that isn't supported.