# How can I infer type with constructor in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have somethig like this

```
class User {
    public name: string
    public age: number
}

class FilterEqual<T, K extends keyof T> {
    constructor(field: K, public value: T[K]) {}
}

new FilterEqual<User, 'name'>('name', '')
```

typescript forces the field parameter to belong to one of the keys of the user class and the value to have the type of the chosen key. Giving errors if we do things like

```
new FilterEqual<User, 'invent'>('invent', '')
new FilterEqual<User, 'name'>('name', 1)
```

This is perfect, it's just what i want BUT it need to repeat the key ¿Does someone know a way to do this?

```
new FilterEqual<User>('name', '')
```

I have tried this:

```
class FilterEqual<T> {
    constructor(field: keyof T, public value: T[keyof T]) {}
}
```

But it would allow this erroneous instance

```
new FilterEqual<User>('name', 1)
```

Comment: I did not understand it correctly. What do u mean by **it needs to repeat the key**? Would you please explain more?

Comment: @mahooresorkh one time on the resolution of generic type and other time as parameter in the constructor . I have to type: `new FilterEqual<User, 'name'>('name', '')` instance of `new FilterEqual<User>('name', '')`

Comment: TS doesn't support partial type argument inference so there's no way to have the compiler infer `K` while you specify `T`.  Various workarounds are described in the answers to [the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56043642/can-i-use-type-as-value-or-correctly-infer-generic-class-type-from-constructor)

Comment: The workarounds look like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w8x44w), by the way