# How correct typing result function. useVuelidate

Tags: typescript, vue.js, typing, vuelidate

I have created a class responsible for validation using a plugin

Example rules&formdata

```
const data = {
    rules: {
      login: base({}),
      password: password
    },
    formData: reactive({
      login: '',
      password: '',
      remember_me: false
    }
```

Rules are other objects with validation methods

```
export const base = ({ min = 2, max = 255 }) => {
  return {
    minLength: ValidatorErrorMsgVuelidate.minLength(min),
    maxLength: ValidatorErrorMsgVuelidate.maxLength(max),
    required: ValidatorErrorMsgVuelidate.required()
  }
}
```

My class

```
export default class ValidatorVuelidate {
  constructor(rules, formData) {
    this.v$ = useVuelidate(rules, formData)
  }

  public validateField = (event: Event): void => {
    const eventTarget = event.target as HTMLInputElement
    const nameField = eventTarget.name
    this.v$.value[nameField].$touch()
    if (this.v$.value[nameField].$error) {
      this.v$.value[nameField].$validate()
    }
  }

  public validateForm = (): boolean | void => {
    this.v$.value.$validate()
    if (this.v$.value.$error) {
      return this.v$.value.$touch()
    }
    return true
  }

  public resetValidateField = (nameField: string): void => {
    this.v$.value[nameField].$reset()
  }
}
```

v$ includes several methods and field names, which we pass to FormData
Example:

```
v$.value.$touch()
```

Typeing useVuelidate

```
export function useVuelidate(globalConfig?: GlobalConfig): Ref<Validation>;
export function useVuelidate<
  T extends {[key in keyof Vargs]: any},
  Vargs extends ValidationArgs = ValidationArgs,
  EState extends ExtractState<Vargs> = ExtractState<Vargs>
>(
  validationsArgs: Ref<Vargs> | Vargs,
  state: T | Ref<T> | ToRefs<T>,
  globalConfig?: GlobalConfig
): Ref<Validation<Vargs, T>>;

export default useVuelidate;
```

How do I type v$ so that hints and types work out most correctly?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . It's unclear what happens in your case.In case the problem is that v$ doesn't have the expected data types, that's because you don't provide them, `ReturnType<typeof useVuelidate>` doesn't contain your data. $v type is supposed to be inferred, that's how composition api usually works. Can be XY problem.  Why is there a constructor? Sticking to classes can be a footgun with composition.

Comment: @EstusFlask, thank you, I have slightly corrected the description of the question

Comment: You'll need to make a class a generic and infer v$ type from params, something like this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56043642/can-i-use-type-as-value-or-correctly-infer-generic-class-type-from-constructor . Using a function that returns validateField, etc fns instead of a class would make it much simpler.

Comment: @EstusFlask, I still can't figure it out. Could you show an example of at least some implementation of useVuelidate?

Comment: I expect it to be something like `function useValidations<T extends ValidationArgs, U extends {[k in keyof T]: any}>(rules: T, formData: U | Ref<U> | ToRefs<U>) { let v$ = useVuelidate(rules, formData); return { v$, validateField: ... } }`. Generic types are borrowed from useVuelidate signature and used in the same way, since this function is a mere wrapper for it. No more explicit types are necessary, the rest are inferred.